# MinGW-w64 not working in windows 7

Tags: mingw, fortran, mingw-w64

I want to use MinGW-64 to build 64-bit fortran programs. It works fine in Windows 8 but it does not work in windows 7 (which I need to work). The error is:
gfortran: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

I know that this problem has been asked alot before, but I really couldn't find the solution.
If there is any solution around, please let me know.
thanks

Comment: Which MinGW-w64 package did you use, how did you "install" it, and what commands did you execute (PATH and the gfortran command)?

Comment: Paste the output for trying to compiler a simple program with the `-v` option which should show which executable is failing the `CreateProcess()` - that may give more of a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps, I have never had problems under Windows 7 with the gcc toolchain installed with Rtools ([here](http://cran.r-project.org/)). It's the compiler used to build programs for the statistical package R, but one can also compile standalone programs. It has gcc, g++ and gfortran, and both 32 bit and 64 bit compilers.